# PIG SCRIPT FAILS with ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias. Backend error : null

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I m trying to execute a pig script with date filter for copying the count of records from hadoop file to a local unix file as below.

```
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/piggybank.jar; 
DEFINE SUBSTRING org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.SUBSTRING(); 
DEFINE SequenceFileLoaderorg.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader();
fixed_length_input = load '/data/publish/mp_feedfixed/**2016/02/24**/??/mp_feed_201602*/part-m-*' USING  
SequenceFileLoader as (key:chararray, value:chararray) ;
st = FOREACH fixed_length_input GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(value, '\u0007', 1)) 
as (row:chararray);
count_st = foreach (GROUP st ALL) generate COUNT(st);
dump count_st;
```

I am getting the above mentioned error

> (ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias count_st. Backend error : null)

only for one particular date. I am able to execute for rest of the dates and hence I felt there is a problem with the files on that date it is looking into. But I could not figure it.

I am new to Hadoop, Can anyone please help solving this issue.

Comment: did it create child job ? check their logs

Comment: Did you checked if the particular date's data available? If yes is it has the same format?

Comment: Try to give the permission to the file which you load because some time it cann't load because of permission